# Использование инкрементов в арифметических операциях

Tags: java, инкремент

Пожалуйста, помогите!

Есть такая операция:

```
int i = 1;
i = i++ + (i++ * i++) + i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

Результат == 11.

Но я не ПОНИМАЮ как... Если по шагам, поправьте пожалуйста:

1. Выполняем операцию в скобках, умножение. 1 * (i становится равным 2) 2 = 2;
2. Далее, слева направо: 2 + 2(i становится == 3) = 4
3. 4 + 3 = 7.

Ответ, конечно, неверный... Но где я допустил ошибку?

Эта преграда тормозит мое обучение, очень хочу понять. Буду рад развернутому ответу...

Comment: Скажите, какому обучению? Это какое-то задание от преподавателя? Просто учтите: на практике никто подобные выражения не пишет. Они вызывают UB в зависимости от языка, такие конструкции нечитаемы и авторам таких мемуаров желательно отрывать руки)) Поэтому этот пример можно даже не разбирать в силу его бессмысленности)

Comment: Я, на старости лет, изучаю Java самостоятельно. И просто хочу понять базовые вещи, как что работает.

Comment: Оператор `+` левоассоциативный, так что сначала выполнится первый `i++` и далее по тексту. Получится `1 + (2 * 3) + 4`

Comment: Спасибо, меня вел в заблуждение приоритет выполнения арифметических операций...

Comment: @kopetan я думаю базовых знаний об инкременте декременте достаточно будет вместо таких конструкций. Тем более, как я уже писал - в зависимости от языка и даже компилятора вычисление выражения может несколько зависеть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = 1 + (2 * 3) + 4
```

Последнюю постинкрементацию можно не рассматривать, т.к. **эта операция игнорируется** (всё равно записываем результат в ту же операцию).

Существует **приоритет** операций. Но *его можно изменять с помощью скобок*. В скобках находится операция умножения, а она по приоритету **ниже** постинкремента. Ведь постинкремент применяется к переменным. А для того, чтобы сформировать конечную операцию для сложения/умножения **ЧИСЕЛ**, а не ссылок на эти числа, изначально нужно во все места с переменными подставить конкретные числа.

Это моё предположение, *могу быть не прав*.